# Want to run cc cleaner over network - need batch file that prompts for computer name and user name.

Tags: file, batch-file

I want to be able to run a .bat file on my local computer where it will execute the command:
PSEXEC \Taylor-PC -c “C:\Users\Taylor\Downloads\Clean.exe” -u TaylorGibb –p Password

Where the 
    \Taylor-PC with the DNS name of the remote machine.

```
TaylorGibb with the username on the remote machine.

Password with the password for the remote machine.
```

Basically I want the person who runs the script to be able to put in the remote machine, hit enter, then username, hit enter, then password, hit enter and it runs cc cleaner.

Comment: Did you googled or tried anything before asking?

Comment: I did but I'm in over my head with this. New to scripting.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
set/p "password=Enter password: "
echo %password%
set/p "computer=Enter computer name: "
echo %computer%
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I incorporate that into my existing script? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: to answer this, we must know the existing script.